# create unique url after submit

Tags: url, unique

i have a form with a questionlist on it. After submit, the given answers on the question are echoed on the same page. ( form is under the php code and action is empty).
Is it possible to generate a unique url after the form is submitted?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by generate a unique URL *after* the form is submitted.

The easiest way is to use a GET request. The URL will have the query parameters as part of it.

So in your form you could have

```
 <form method="GET" ...>
 ...
 <input type="text" name="answer[0]">
 <input type="text" name="answer[1]">
 ...
```

If the user submits the form, the browser will request the url `http://your.domain/same_page?answer[0]=42&answer[1]=...`